# Ace.js .on event

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have a few **ace.js** editors on one page. They are stored in an array.

How to determine the editor where I enter text?

```
var editor = {first: ace.edit("editor"), second: ace.edit("editor1"), third: ace.edit("editor2")};

for(var i in editor) {
    editor[i].getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    editor[i].on('input', function() {
        console.log(this); // How to get current editor? this returns [function()]
    });
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3nHas/25/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the element? Or an instance of the editor? Regardless, you should find what you need in the second parameter of the called function.

```
editor[i].on('input', function(e, target) {
    console.log(target);
});
```